# minimum eigenvalue of sub rows of a projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix $P = I - X (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$ where $X$ has dimension $n \times s$ and $s < n$. Clearly $\lambda_{\min}(P) = 0$. But can we say something about the minimum eigenvalue on the sub-matrix of $P$? In particular, if we take $t$ rows of $P$, will it have positive smallest singular value? I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is a Gaussian ensemble or say the rows of $X$ are from some Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_{s \times s})$.

Comment: If you delete any row of $P$ you no longer have a square matrix.

Comment: whether the smallest singular value is positive or not.

Comment: The eigenvalues of a projection are $0$ and $1$. I’d guess that you have to delete at least a number of rows equal to $P$’s nullity for the minimum to change.